# Beginning AI programming

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am really interested in AI and want to start programming in this field.

What are the various areas within AI? e.g. Neural Networks etc.

What book can be recommended for a beginner in AI and are there any preferred languages used in the field of AI?

Comment: I think questions asking for resources relating to a field of programming are ok, so I don't get the "off topic" classification. Where should those questions go?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Classical *application* areas of AI:

- Robotics
- Search
- Natural Language Processing
- Knowledge Representation / Expert Systems
- Planning / Scheduling

Various *algorithmic* approaches:

- Neural Networks
- Evolutionary / Genetic Algorithms
- Automatic Reasoning
- Logic Programming
- Probablilistic Approaches

Recommendable books:

- Norvig, Russel: Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach
- Norvig: Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming (uses Lisp)
- Bratko: Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence

Recommendable programming languages:

- Prolog
- Lisp
- Java (many algorithms are discussed in Java nowadays)

There are also a number of interesting answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006793/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-started-in-artificial-intelligence-programming) (which sort of covers the same ground).

Comment: Im surprised C isnt recommended for AI? Reason?

Comment: @Helium3 - C is very procedural; good for device drivers, or perhaps the nuts-and-bolts of connectionist frameworks. Languages like Lisp and Scheme are much more natural for the sort of symbolic processing encountered in classical AI.

Comment: @Helium This probably deserves a question of its own. In short: C is very good at implementing operating systems or interpreters. But it forces you to think too much in terms of low-level machine concepts (memory, registers, ...), and is not very amenable to high-level concepts (relations, logic, symbols, ...).