# Artificial Intelligence for a Chess game

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am new to Artificial programming and I was asked to make a program that stores the moves taken every time and so on. Can anyone of you can give me an idea just to how artificial works and how I should proceed?

Comment: If you add the programming language that you would like to use, that might help people answer your question a little better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you will have to take a look at languages you can use for AI, have a look at (this is if you want to go really advanced) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_for_artificial_intelligence

Then you can have a look at some tutorials to guide you:
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/artificial-intelligence/chess-programming-part-i-getting-started-r1014

Note that this can get very complicated, depending on how advanced you want your AI to be. There are also a number of different algorithms that you can use.

This is quite a widely discussed subject, especially with the game of Chess. Google should have all the answers you are looking for.

Some links that you might find helpful:
http://www.aihorizon.com/essays/chessai/intro.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence

http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-learn-Artificial-Intelligence-for-a-beginner

http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=14779

[Beginning AI programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927339/beginning-ai-programming)

Comment: No problem! All the best!